# How to read FirebaseDatabase DEBUG logs in app?

Tags: android, firebase, logging, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to figure out an issue and it could be helpful to analyze the FirebaseDatabase DEBUG logs during the app execution to display useful information to the user or take decisions (for example retry some operations).

I found the following instruction to set the FirebaseDatabase logs to debug but my problem is that it seems that the logs are only logged on logcat and from the app execution there isn't any chance to retrieve any log.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)
```

Is it possible to access to these logs on app?

Thanks!

Manuela.

Answer (score 1):

Logs don't go away when an app terminates.  If you're using Android Studio, you have to use the dropdown to indicate that you want to view all of the logs (not just the ones from a currently running process).  Or you can use `adb logcat` to view them from a command prompt.

Comment: I do not have access to the phone directly, I want to read these FirebaseDatabase debug logs and show them to the user using some dialog or post them to my backend server to perform further analysis

Comment: There's unfortunately no way to do that from Firebase. There might be a way to read logcat output in general, but I've never looked into that. If you think the problem your users are having is in establishing the connection, you could send to the (incredibly old) https://www.firebase.com/test.html page. If that reproduces the problem, they can copy/paste the log output from there.

Comment: If you want to collect logcat output from a remote device, you're going have to arrange to instead log to another service that will collect and store those for you.  Crashlytics might be able to help you with that.